# My program is not asking for input

Tags: c++

I am writing a program and it is a long program and I have just started. I just tested it for running, Please tell me why it is not having user input:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct courses{
    int CLO1, CLO2, CLO3, CLO4, CLO5;
    int tcounter;
};
int main(){
    cin.clear();
    courses C1;
    C1.CLO1;
    C1.CLO2;
    C1.CLO3;
    int counter = 0;
    char name;
    cout << "Enter your Name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "For C1, we have three CLOs that CLO1,CLO2 and CLO3. CLO1 and CLO3 are linked to PLO1 and CLO2 is linked to PLO2 " << endl;
    cout << "Enter your marks in CLO1 for C1:(Out of 10) ";
    cin >> C1.CLO1;
    if (C1.CLO1 >= 5){
        counter++;
    }
    cout << "Enter your marks in CLO2 for C1:(Out of 10) ";
    cin >> C1.CLO2;
    if (C1.CLO2 >= 5){
        counter++;
    }
    cout << "Enter your marks in CLO3 for C1:(Out of 10) ";
    cin >> C1.CLO3;
    if (C1.CLO3 >= 5){
        counter++;
    }
    cout << counter;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is name a char and not std::string?

Answer (score 0):

As per me the program is fine.
Three things you need to change:

1. variable type of name from char to string
2. C1.CLO1;C1.CLO2;C1.CLO3; remove these from your code it doesn't make any sense.
3. Print the values and check :P